# Redmine installation - Ruby MySQL connector issue

Tags: installation, mysql, ruby, redmine, gem

I am trying to migrate from TRAC to Redmine,
though i encountered a problem with the installation procedure.

i follow the install guide at : http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall
and everything got allright...

- created the redmine database (empty) in MySQL5.5,
  added the user redmine, and for testing used 'my_password' as password
- copied the mysqllib.dll from the `MySQL Connector/C 6.0.2` to `c:\ruby193\bin`   as suggested after executing `bundle install -without rmagick`
- edited `database.yml` with :

> production:
>        adapter: mysql2
>        database: redmine
>        host: localhost
>        username: redmine
>        password: my_password

- then `set RAILS_ENV=production`
- when i tried to generate the tables using `rake db:migrate`
  i got the following error (additng --trace):

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\redMine 2.1-stable>rake db:migrate --trace
  ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
  ** Invoke environment (first_time)
  ** Execute environment
  rake aborted!
  Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:170:in `retrieve_connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:144:in `connection'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__792713192__prepare__98754910__callbacks'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  C:/Program Files (x86)/redMine 2.1-stable/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:295:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `each'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:185:in `invoke_prerequisites'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
  C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
  ```

Versions information:
Windows 7 x64 Professional
MySql 5.5.4
MySql Connector/C 6.0.2
ruby -v => ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]
gem -v => 1.8.24

- Tested the login using MySQL Workbench... working correctly.

Please help, what should i check?

Answer (score 0):

Well just ****ing amazing !
ya, an angry at myself post :)

after 1 hour fighting to find a solution, i post this question...

5 minutes after posting this question i see the solution in StackOverflow...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892689/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061-after-installation

> Just not use `localhost`
>   but use `127.0.0.1` instead !

beautiful... i feel so dumb... but better turn out this way...
hope noone will need to handle this anymore :~)